# When can you replace some random variable $X$ with another random variable $Y$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Is there some condition that one random variable $X$ can be replaced by some other random variable $Y$ provided that $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are consistent then renaming will do no harm. Replacing is another thing. For instance if you are asked to calculate the expectation of $X^{2}=X\times X$ where $X$ is symmetrically distributed rv (i.e $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution) then you cannot replace the second $X$ by $-X$ wich would lead to the calculation of the expectation of $X\times (-X)=-X^{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like renaming your random variable, feel free to do it, but don't forget that variables $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Comment: Gotta love this answer.